# A general form of a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have difficulty evaluating the following double integral:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{(x-y)^2+m^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y$$

where m is a constant.

I've tried to use substitution $x-y=m\tan u$ to calculate the inner part:

$$\int\sec^3 u\text{d}u=\frac{m^2}{2}(\tan u\sec u+\ln|\tan u+\sec u|)+C$$

where $u=\arctan\frac{x-y}{m}$, I also need to integrate the outer part. It seems that I made the problem even complex.

I've also tried to use polar coordinates, but can I use substitution like this?

$$x-y=r\cos\theta, m=r\sin\theta$$

Comment: You have two variables x and y. You can't use polar substitution where m is like a "y in classic polar coordinates". When you use substitutions in double integrals you must do a nonsingular plane transform. Try to use s = x - y, t = x + y it's a classic substitution for such integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a change of variables

\begin{align*}
    u&=x-y\\
    v&=x+y
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{(x-y)^2+m^2}\,dxdy&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\int_{|u|}^{2-|u|}\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\,dvdu\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1(2-2|u|)\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\,du\\
&=2\int_{0}^1(1-u)\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\,du
\end{align*}
Break this into two parts:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1u\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\,du&\overset{u^2=w}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1\sqrt{w+m^2}\,dw\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(w+m^2)^{3/2}|_0^1\\
&=\frac{1}{3}((1+m^2)^{3/2}-m^3)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\,du&\overset{u=m\sinh z}{=}\int_{0}^{\sinh^{-1}(m^{-1})}\sqrt{m^2\sinh^2 z+m^2}\,m\cosh z\,dz\\
&=\int_{0}^{\sinh^{-1}(m^{-1})}m^2\cosh^2 z\,dz\\
&=m^2\frac{1}{2}(z+\sinh z \cosh z)|_{0}^{\sinh^{-1}(m^{-1})}\\
&=m^2\frac{1}{2}(\sinh^{-1}(m^{-1})+m^{-1} \sqrt{1+m^{-2}})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(m^2\sinh^{-1}(m^{-1})+ \sqrt{1+m^2})
\end{align*}
So, all together
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{(x-y)^2+m^2}\,dxdy
&=2\int_{0}^1(1-u)\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\,du\\
&=m^2\sinh^{-1}(m^{-1})+ \sqrt{1+m^2}-\frac{2}{3}((1+m^2)^{3/2}-m^3)
\end{align*}

Comment: I wonder if you miss a multiplying factor of $4$.

Comment: I used Wolfram alpha to verify the answer, but it did seem that the answer is actually four times your answer

Comment: I don't know which part goes wrong, but there's a Jacobian coefficient 2, so the first coefficient should be 1/2 instead of 1/8.

Comment: I've fixed it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the same method as @Joshua Tilley, we can derive a different form.

$$I=\int\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\text{d}u$$
Substitue $u=m\tan\phi$, we have

\begin{align*}
    I&=\int m^2\sec^3\phi\\
    &=\frac12 m^2(\sec\phi\tan\phi+\ln|\sec\phi+\tan\phi|)\\
    &=\frac12m^2\left(\frac{u\sqrt{m^2+u^2}}{m^2}+\ln|\frac{u+\sqrt{m^2+u^2}}{m}|\right)\\
    &=\frac12u\sqrt{m^2+u^2}+\frac12m^2\ln\frac{u+\sqrt{m^2+u^2}}{m}
\end{align*}
which implies
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{u^2+m^2}\text{d}u=\frac12\sqrt{m^2+1}+\frac12m^2\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{m^2+1}}{m}$$
Putting them together, we derive
$$\sqrt{m^2+1}+m^2\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{m^2+1}}{m}-\frac23\left(1+m^2\right)^{\frac32}+\frac23m^3$$